# PHP: how parse a simil - XML string?

Tags: php, xml

I need to parse this string:

```
<RESPONSE>
<status>200</status>
<credits>100.00</credits>
</RESPONSE>
```

It seems XML but I think that it is not. In effect, no other tags or other.

I need to parse and extract the , so I can print an output, for example,

```
"<p>Available credits: '.$credits.'</p>"
```

Of course I tried SimpleXMLElement but it doesn't recognize the XML.

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Indeed, that XML is invalid; `<credits>` is not closed. Make sure to get a proper XML or catch an exception when the XML is wrong.

Comment: My mistake, but that simil-XML I receive from a webservice, I cannot change it. I need only to parse to achieve my goal.. Thank you

Comment: What is your SimpleXMLElement code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is valid but lacks XML header. Basically after you add the header you should be able to use SimpleXML:

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>\n" . $similXML;

$response = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $response->credits;
```

Comment: Thank you. In effect adding the header all goes ok. But, I have another problem. I get the $similXML from a CURL call, and PHP add header at the end... I cannot put it in front :( This is my code:       $header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 $result = $header.$response;
 print_r($result);

Comment: When I print_r($result), I obtain first the response from CURL and after the header... :(

Comment: You missing curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); before curl_exec(). In effect you see $similXML printed by cURL, not by your print_r() as $response is empty (having boolean true only).

Comment: You don'T need curl, PHP support HTTP and SimeplXMLElement can open HTTP URLs directly.

Comment: Internal HTTP client of SimpleXMLElement is not that good in handling http errors. cURL returns more diagnostic information which allows to actually handle http errors properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a few static values you can extract them yourself.

To get the credits you would do:

```
if (preg_match('/<credits>([0-9.]+)<\/credits>/', $response, $matches) {
  $credits = $matches[1];
}
```